# Openssl wrong content type while decrypting signed and encrypted SMIME message

Tags: encryption, openssl, smime

I have the following smime message of multipart body.
I am trying to decrypt it with the openSSL command below, using a certificate and a private key. However I get an error of wrong content type.
Does anybody know where this error comes from and how to resolve it?

openssl command

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in enc_signed.txt -recip enc_signed.crt -inkey enc_signed.key
```

smime message

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha1"; boundary="----BC660923488785300E5AA069D494A307"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------BC660923488785300E5AA069D494A307
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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------BC660923488785300E5AA069D494A307
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
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------BC660923488785300E5AA069D494A307--
```

error

```
Error decrypting PKCS#7 structure
3848:error:21072071:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_decrypt:wrong content type:crypto\pkcs7\pk7_smime.c:489:
```

Comment: The error is wrong content _type_ not wrong content. You have a message that was encrypted _and then (clear)signed_; you need to first **remove the signature** -- with or without verification, although if the data in this message is important or valuable verification is good -- and _then_ decrypt the signed portion..

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the instructions. It now works. Also, I corrected the error description. Thanks for pointing it out.